# Categorizar los colores en React JS con Leafltet para un mapa

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, nextjs

estiy usando react js con next para un mapa necesito categorizar por colores unos numeros pero realmente aun no me ha funcionado
Debo sacar de esos colores 6 categorias
pinta un mapa departamentos las categorias son asi:
0= Gris
1-50= un color
51-100
101-200
201-500
501-1000

```
const giveColor = (localidadProperties) => {

    let density = Math.ceil(localidadProperties.density * 10) / 10
    //console.log("density es:", density)
    const gradient = {
        0.0: "#000000",
        0.1: "#56A7E7",
        0.2: "#3D92D5",
        0.3: "#368CCF",
        0.4: "#2C81C3",
        0.5: "#2375B4",
        0.6: "#196AA9",
        0.7: "#125F9B",
        0.8: "#065593",
        0.9: "#064C83",
        1.0: "#064576",
    }
    
    return gradient[density]
};
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el código?

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Me colaboran por favor